# Realistically, will removing the session state request lock actually affect the site

Tags: asp.net, session, redis, thread-safety, session-state

I've been playing with different session state providers for ASP.Net recently and have come up with what appears to be the best (performance and implementation wise).

Using https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore

This works marvelously and is very simple to implement.  The only issue is that it forces the request lock - so the browser has to wait if there is a request open.  This is fine a lot of the time, but when you end up on some long-running process and the user wants to give up, the user is left hanging until the long running process finishes.

Now - this can be resolved by removing the lock from the provider.  This is as easy changing the lines where lock = true to lock = false, and altering the update so it takes no notice of "&& state.Locked  && state.LockId == lockId"

Panic! Clearly this goes against how session state was intended, and in terms of thread safety it's a frightening prospect.  But...in a lot of sites we've built, session state is rarely used for anything more complex than "which user id is currently active" - which gets written very rarely.  It may be used to transfer (large) data between 2 pages, and it may be used to store the odd setting.  ...in a lot of cases thread safety is rarely going to be a problem, so is the performance trade off actually worth it, or is removing the lock and venturing out to get a significantly more responsive site worth the risk?

Answer (score 1):

You can try my version of storing .NET Session in Redis, it goes to great lengths to not lock the session. And from personal experience, we did see a speedup in our heavily AJAX'ed web app after removing the locking:

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RedisSessionProvider

Docs: https://github.com/welegan/RedisSessionProvider

Answer (score -1):

You can also try out aspnet session state provider for redis, this blog here explains about it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx

hope this helps.

Comment: How this helps in order to not get locked by the session provider?